# Limit of Restricted Sum of Multinomial

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $P_{1}, \ldots, P_{d} \in \left[0,1\right]$ be such that $P_{1}+\ldots+P_{d}=1$, and $P:=(P_{1},\ldots,P_{d})$. From the multinomial theorem,

$$
1=(P_{1}+\ldots+P_{d})^n=\sum_{k_1+\ldots+k_d=n}P_{1}^{k_{1}}\ldots P_{d}^{k_{d}}\binom{n}{k_1,\ldots,k_d}\;.
$$

Let

$$
f_{d}(P,n):=\sum_{\substack{k_1+\ldots+k_d=n \\ k_{1}\le \ldots \le k_{d}}}P_{1}^{k_{1}}\ldots P_{d}^{k_{d}}\binom{n}{k_1,\ldots,k_d},
$$ the sum over multinomials with increasing $k_j$'s. The question is: how can we get a handle on $f_{d}$, and in particular $\displaystyle L_{d}(P):=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_{d}(P,n)$.

In the simplest case, $d=2$, Mathematica spits out

$$f_{2}(\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right),2k)=2^{-2k}\binom{2k}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(k+1)}{2\Gamma(k+\frac{1}{2})}\right)$$

Taking the limit, $L_{2}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$. It seems that if $P_{1}>P_{2}$, then $L_{2}(P)=1$ and if $P_{1}<P_{2}$, then $L_{2}(P)=0$.

Let $\Delta$ denote the region in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ such that $x_{1} \le \ldots \le x_{d}$. For $d>2$, I expect that $L_{d}(P)=0$ if $P \not\in \Delta$. I'd guess that $0 < L_{d}(P) < 1$ if $P \in \partial \Delta$, and $L_{d}(P)=1$ if $P \in \text{int}(\Delta)$.